# I perform google app script to generate PDF centification but got stuck to create PDF file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am performing google app script to generate PDF certification and send to participants passing quiz score as desired criteria, but in the Process 4 I cannot still create PDF file because `getAS()` method does not work at the end of replace name of participant in google slide template.

Here is my google app script:

```js
//Process 1 Specify the source of data, template and folder
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1KXhXgRYN2-cgxeeHdNT8425gemAwtWYQABPfMlYp_Kc');
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1')
var folderID = '1fv2sHqG8Su7Qt4njTv3qcIllhLct4d--'
var TemplateID = '1yAO4Q4AKZjP_5v9lta5qvxtk2bBJnZWYLVMt68at5RQ'
function myFunction() {
  var rngData = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  //Iterate to all data in google sheet and filter score base on desire criteria
  for (i = 1; i < rngData.length; i++) {
    var score = rngData[i][1];
    if (score >= 14) {
      var fullname = rngData[i][3] + "" + rngData[i][20];
      var email = rngData[i][4];
      
      //Process 2 Access to Slide Template
      var temp = DriveApp.getFileById(TemplateID);
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
      
      //Process 3 Copy Template to destination folder
        var SlideCopy = temp.makeCopy(folder);
        var newSlideID = SlideCopy.getId();
        var newCert = SlidesApp.openById(newSlideID);
        var slides = newCert.getSlides();
        var slideContent = slides[0].getShapes();
    
      //Process 4. Loop to replace name of participants in all copied slides at placeholder
      for(j = 0 ; j < slideContent.length ; j++){
              //Replace the name of participant in placeholder
               slideContent[j].getText().replaceAllText('{fullname}',fullname);
               //rename the file of slide by participant name
               newCert.setName(fullname);
      }     
    }
  }
}
```

My result is created PDF file generating from that script.